# MATLAB- Individually Saving Workspace Variables into Many Individual .mat Files

Tags: matlab, save, syntax-error, workspace

So I have many files in a MATLAB workspace all in the same format,

"project1day1", "project1day2" etc. and instead of having them all in the same workspace, I want to save them as their own individual .mat files with the same name.

So, I want the "project1day1" variable in the workspace to go to a "project1day1.mat" file.

I have 7 projects, and all of them except for project 1 has 3 "days". I was having trouble executing the exact syntax to do it. I want to loop through my workspace data in a general fashion. I want to execute something along the lines of:

```
maxdays=3;
maxprojects=7;

for i = 1:maxprojects;
  for j = 1:maxdays;

     save('project%dday%d','project%dday%d,i,j,i,j)

  end
end
```

Two things:

1) The save option isn't working

2) I need to include some sort of ~if(exist '...') for the case where there isn't a 3rd day, but I'm having trouble doing so.

Comment: I would advise against having many MAT files.... instead, have ONE MAT file that contains all of these variables.  Having too many MAT files would make things unmanageable.  If this is something you're interested in, I will write an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As rayryeng wrote, I think in most cases it would be better to either save the variables in one file, or (you wrote they are all in the same format) use a structure or a cell array, which makes it much easier to access them later.

If you really need to save all variables in the workspace to separate files you **can** do something like this:

```
vars = who;

for i=1:length(vars)
    save([vars{i} '.mat'], vars{i});
end
```

But again, I wouldn't do this if it is not (for some reason) absolutely necessary!

Comment: Try and avoid using `eval`. You can just do `save([vars{i} '.mat'], vars{i});` Using `eval` is considered bad practice.  If you have time, please read this informative article by Loren Shure from MathWorks: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/

Comment: i know, for some reason I thought MATLAB needs the quotes around the variable name...edited it, thanks

Comment: **Hint:** you could use [regexp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to filter out undesired variables. Just replace the first line with this: `vars = regexp(strjoin(who.'), 'project\d+day\d+', 'match');`

Comment: for most purposes wildcard expressions like `who('project*') ` should be sufficient